# ios restkit 0.24 with oauth2

Tags: oauth, afnetworking, afoauth2client

I am iOS newbie attempting to use RestKit to connect to a service that uses OAuth2. I have had no success in finding examples on how to sent the bearer token when making requests (I am trying a GET request). I found a post where a suggestion was made to use AFOAuth2Manager, but I am not sure how to make it work.

I tried installing AFOAuth2Manager using CocoaPods and got an exception that indicated that RestKit relies on AFNetworking 1.3.3 but AFOAuth2Manager requires a higher version (2.x.x).

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I am experiencing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

You've hit a dependency problem. Try using `AFOAuth2Client` instead.

```
pod 'AFOAuth2Client'
```

I know it is deprecated but you just can't use AFOAuth2Manager with RestKit